# Проблема с месностью тиррейна

Tags: unity3d

Сегодня заметил проблему, на тиррейне рисую текстурами области, используется 7 текстур, для разных месностей.
Открываю на мобиле и начинаются лаги и задержки.
Размер тиррейна 800 на 600.

Когда оставляю одну текстуру, все работает плавно.

С чего возникает такая проблема и как ее решать?
Не ужели все на столько плохо у `Unity`?

Был бы рад решением, а то уж больно много сил влито в создание.

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и как ее решал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменил текстуры и модели деревьев, травы, и все нормально стало, видать, что-то с текстурами было и моделями деревьев, травы.